# i have runtime erorr '3219' in vb6, it says that my code is "operation is not allowed in this context",

Tags: vb6

code that not allowed is read function "pdffile.read", i already try to get preference but is not working

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
   Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

   rs.Open "select * from tble1", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
   rs.AddNew
   If pdfpath <> "" Then
      Set pdffile = New ADODB.stream
      pdffiletype = adtypebinary
      pdffile.Open
      pdffile.loadfromfile pdfpath

      rs.Fields("pdf") = pdffile.read
      rs!pdfid = txt.Text
      rs!pdfname = txtname.Text

      pdffile.Close
      Set pdffile = Nothing
      pdffile.Close
      Set pdffile = Nothing
   End If

   rs.Update
   rs.Close
   Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: adtypebinary is lowercase indicating your using late binding and may not be specifying a value for the named const, is that the case?  What data type is the pdf column?

Comment: Did you perhaps forget to open the connection `cn`?

Comment: What does pdffile.read return? If it is an object you need `set` at the start of the line.